# Calculating the value of a column based on the values of other columns

Tags: arcpy

[image]Please correct my code for calculating the value of a column "New_score" for each value of ID_TRC using the values of 3 other columns called LENGTH, Category, and Score. 
for each ID_TRC, "if the ID_TRC is repeating" with different values for Category and length---

New_score= summation(LENGTH*Score)/Summation(LENGTH),

if the category is different, but the length is equal-

New_score= summation(LENGTH*Score)/LENGTH

else the Score = New_score

```
from tkinter import *
import arcpy

fc = "C:/Users/umroot/Desktop/tersoo/GIS_data/GUI_CODES/output/LandUse_Roads.shp"
field = "ID_TRC, LENGTH, Categorie, Score"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    ID_TRC = row.getValue('ID_TRC')
    LENGTH = row.getValue('LENGTH')
    Categorie = row.getValue('Categorie')
    Score = row.getValue('Score')
    rowCur = row
    rowPost = cursor.next()
    while ID_TRC:
        ScoreSum = 0.0
        LengthSum = 0.0
        if Categorie != rowPost.getValue('Categorie'):
            if LENGTH != rowPost.getValue('LENGTH'):
                ScoreSum += Score*LENGTH
                LengthSum+= LENGTH
                New_score = ScoreSum/LengthSum
                print("different lengths",ID_TRC,New_score)
            else:
               ScoreSum += Score*LENGTH
               New_score = ScoreSum/LENGTH
               print("equal length",ID_TRC, New_score)
        else:
            New_score = Score
            print("same category",ID_TRC, New_score)
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image: SAMPLE TABLE]

Comment: First rule of ArcPy cursors: Only use DA Cursors, never "old" cursors.  You're using an old cursor.

Comment: @Vince - from https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/data-access-using-cursors.htm ... A new data access module (arcpy.da) was added in ArcGIS 10.1. The previously existing cursors (that are still listed under arcpy) are still functional and valid...

Comment: the biggest problem here is you are calling .updateRow on a SearchCursor. cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc) -> cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

Comment: problem #2 .. when using an update cursor, you need to include the field being updated in the field list as in -> field = "ID_TRC, LENGTH, Categorie, Score, New_Score"

Comment: problem #3 ... when calling updateRow(row) : row should be "A list or tuple of values. The order of values should be in the same order as the fields." as per http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm. In your example ... you are passing the un-modified row to cursor.updateRow because row is not changed anywhere in your for block

Comment: If I'm undertanding you correctly, this will require a set of nested cursors where the outer cursor is an UpdateCursor iterating the entire table, and the inner cursor is a SearchCursor used to perform the aggregate analysis of the potentially repeated ID_TRC subset. Take care to release the SearchCursor on each iteration of the outer UpdateCursor as these things can blow up in memory.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions, but I would be most grateful if you all could just correct my code....

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information here yet to correct your code entirely

1. your conditional logic is order dependent (probably not what you're wanting here)
2. you haven't provided any output showing the desired result.

But here's my first stab @ it (I haven't tested this at all, just wanted to use it to illustrate the nested cursor pattern):

```
import arcpy

fc = "C:/Users/umroot/Desktop/tersoo/GIS_data/GUI_CODES/output/LandUse_Roads.shp"

#Include all fields that are used by either the Outer UpdateCursor or Inner SearchCursor
fields = "ID_TRC, LENGTH, categorie, Score, New_Score"

#Outer UpdateCursor for iterating {row}'s
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # these are variables holding individual field values from {row}
        m_id_trc = row[0]
        m_length = row[1]
        m_categorie = row[2]
        m_score = row[3]

        # these are variables for aggregate results from the conditional logic in sub_cursor
        # these will be reset for each new Outer {row}
        # these will NOT be reset for each new Inner {sub_row}
        ScoreSum = 0.0
        LengthSum = 0.0
        New_Score = 0.0 # Aggregate result we wish to update on {row} after iterating all {sub_row}'s

        #Inner SearchCursor for iterating {sub_row}'s
        #Here we use a {where-clause} to limit the record set to records matching ID_TRC on the Outer {row}
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields, "ID_TRC = " + str(m_id_trc)) as sub_cursor:
            for sub_row in sub_cursor:
                # these are variables holding individual field values from {sub_row}
                sub_id_trc = row[0]
                sub_length = row[1]
                sub_categorie = row[2]
                sub_score = row[3]

                #Aggregate Logic
                #I suspect this is not the correct logic because it is dependent on {sub_row} order!
                if m_categorie != sub_categorie:
                    if m_length != sub_length:
                        ScoreSum += sub_score*sub_length
                        LengthSum += sub_length
                        New_Score = ScoreSum/LengthSum
                        print("different lengths",ID_TRC,New_Score)
                    else: #Equal Length
                       ScoreSum += sub_score*sub_length
                       New_Score = ScoreSum/sub_length
                       print("equal length",ID_TRC, New_Score)
                else: #Equal categorie
                    New_Score = m_score
                    print("same category",ID_TRC, New_Score)
                #End if
            #End for sub_row
        #End with sub_cursor
        row[5] = New_Score
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    #End for row
#End with cursor
```

When I say it's order dependent, I mean the order of {sub_row}'s returned by the sub_cursor iterator will dictate the value of {New_Score}. Normally when performing aggregate analysis, we look to write a set of conditionals that is order independent. If I knew the desired results, I could probably reverse engineer the logic.

(Don't feel bad ... ask me how many times I mispelled dependent)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robbie,  I just have tested the code, and there are a couple of issues.      I. only the last else statement is executed, 2. the output should be the unique values of m_id_trc along with the corresponding new _score., 3. if the value of ID_TRC is repeated twice or more, it prints all the values and a new_score for each value, instead of just one value and its corresponding new_score

Comment: I can't follow the logic, if you will post the desired results for the table you included I will reverse engineer the logic from the desired results and provide a working solution.

Comment: I have added the expected output. The new table should consist of only the ID and the corresponding new scores. Thanks a lot